# $addFields in mongoDB aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I'm using the cloud mongoDB atlas online version of the aggregation pipeline builder. 
My document looks like this:

```
_id: 'a314314133351sd4d'
type: 'Test_993das'
```

What I want to achieve is that I get an custom field with name customField that counts all the documents that have a substring Test in type:

```
customField: 6
```

However when I use stage $addFields nothing works with strings. Even stuff from the docs. 
It seems that $regexMatch is not recognized in addFields stage even though the docs suggest this should be possible.

```
{ $addFields: { customField: { $regexMatch: { input: "$type", regex: "Test_*" } }
```

Comment: As `$regexMatch` is a 'new' operation i'm assuming your Mongo version is less than 4.2 which is the version where this operator was introduced.

Comment: That is true. Thanks @tomslabbaert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by tom slabbaert, `$regexMatch` is available only on MongoDB 4.2.x, also, your regex is not valid (should either be `Test_` or `Test_.*`).

However, the syntax you are using will only produce `customField: true` (or `false`), not a count. Counts are aggregate functions and therefore need to operate on a group of documents. An aggregation pipeline operates on each single document unless you use a grouping stage like `$group`, `$bucket` or `$count`.

What this means is that, in your example, `$addField` will evaluate the regex and add the field on **each** document. So probably you want something like:

```
[
  { $match: { 'type': { $regex: /Test_.*/ } } },
  { $count: 'customField' }
]
```

Also, if your regex should match only the start of the string, you will get better performance if you anchor the regex, like this: `/^Test_.*/`

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  $addFields: {
    hasNewMessage: {
      $cond: { if: {$gt: [{ $size: "$messages" }, 0]}, then: true, else: false}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you should provide some background to your answer with brief explanation on what the code does.